# Returning values from a method with multiple variables

Tags: java

The problem I'm having is that I don't know how to call the methods in main to make them work.

First I ask the user what shape does he wants to calculate it's area in the method "public static void userInput". The user has 3 options to select from.

Then there are the 3 methods, 1 for the circle, 1 for the triangle and 1 for the square.

```
public static void userInput(double radius, int base, int height, int side){

    int object = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
    "Enter 1 if you want to know the area of a circle."
    \nEnter 2 if you want to know the area of a triangle.
    \nEnter 3 if you want to know the area of a square"));

    if (object == 1){
        radius = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the radius"));


    }else if (object == 2){
        base = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the base"));
        height = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the height"));


    }else if (object == 3){
        side = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the side"));

    }
}


public static double circle(){
    double radio = 0;
    double circle = (radio * radio) * 3.14159265358; 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The circle area is "+circle);
    return circle;
}

public static int triangle(){
    int base= 0; 
    int height= 0;
    int triangle = (base * height)/2;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The triangle area is "+triangle);
    return triangle;
}

public static int square(){
    int side = 0;
    int square = side * side;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The square area is "+square);
    return square;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    circle(userInput(radius));
    triangle(userInput(base, height));
    square(userInput(side));
}
```

Can anyone recommend a good read about methods?

Comment: This will help you to understand about Java Methods [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_methods.htm)

Comment: [Oracle's Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)

Comment: Considering that you are a beginner i'd recommend to read a book that explains ALL the language, Thinking in Java or Head First Java should be perfect for you, check them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this is what you looked for:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class NewClass1 {
    public void userInput(int x){



    if (x == 1){
        double radius = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the radius"));
        System.out.println(circle(radius));


    }else if (x == 2){
        int base = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the base"));
        int height = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the height"));
        System.out.println(triangle(base,height));

    }else if (x == 3){
        int side = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the side"));
        System.out.println(square(side));
    }
}


public static double circle(double radio){

    double circle = (radio * radio) * 3.14159265358; 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The circle area is "+circle);
    return circle;
}

public static int triangle(int base,int height){
    int triangle = (base * height)/2;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The triangle area is "+triangle);
    return triangle;
}

public static int square(int side){
    int square = side * side;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The square area is "+square);
    return square;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    NewClass1 obj = new NewClass1();
    int object = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
    "Enter 1 if you want to know the area of a circle\nEnter 2 if you want to know the area of a triangle.\nEnter 3 if you want to know the area of a square"));
    obj.userInput(object);
}
}
```

Try doing some practices on the Java Methods.

Comment: "Try doing some practices on the Java Methods." That is what I will be doing this week.

Comment: Is the answer I provided is Correct?

Comment: Yes thanks. This 2 lines are new to me "NewClass1 obj = new NewClass1();" and "obj.userInput(object);"

Comment: The first one is when I created the object of the class **NewClass1**. Every object created from a class has all the methods defined in the class. Then I passed the user input value **object** to the method **Userinput**. There through if statements required polygon is selected.

Comment: Interesting. The "System.out.println" is what is binding the methods.

Comment: **System.out.println** used to display the output. The methods you created for each shape is static ones . There for no need to create objects. There for its free to call by its name and use anytime link inside the **System.out.println(circle(radius))** calls the circle method passing radius as argument.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have pasted in your question is incomplete but as per your question:

to Returning values from a method with multiple variables?

You can use object of a class to return multiple variables.

Comment: structs are part of the c family of languages; they are not part of java

Comment: In java you can return an object of a class